# Is oxygen a respiratory substrate

Tags: cellular-respiration

I know that carbohydrates such as glucose are respiratory substrates for cellular respiration, but in this process, oxygen is also used to produce ATP so is it also a respiratory substrate?

Comment: I don't know if I've ever heard the term "respiratory substrate" before. But, I've said it many times on stackexchange, so I guess I'll say it once more.. I *hate* semantics. And, I really do not see the importance in being able to define something by some arbitrary human idea. So, what is important?.. What is important is that you know what everything, as a single entity, does on its own. Can you tell me what the function of oxygen is in the body? What happens to it? Where does it go?

Comment: By the way.. Welcome to stack exchange! [Here's a link to a nice overview of what we're all about](https://biology.stackexchange.com/tour)

Comment: You must explain what you understand the term "respiratory substrate" to mean if you know glucose is one. Also respiratory, in a biochemical sense. Then we can answer your question, but by that time you should be able to answer it yourself.